# JAVA Integer Trouble

Tags: java, call

I have written a sorting algorithm (bubble) and I have used 10000 unique values i.e.

```
int BubArray[] = new int[]{#10000 unique unsorted values#};
```

I was wondering how I would put the integers into a file and call the file instead of the 10000 integers in the code.

Also in which format would they go (with commas, spaces?) I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use simple file handling also it is upto you to go with commas,spaces. It depends.

Comment: why don't you use Random class to generate 10000 random values?

Comment: @BhavikShah because how do you know the bubble algorithm worked and the Random class did not just generated 1000 random values completely sorted? J/K

Comment: @Averroes : it never generates values in sorted order

Comment: @Averroes it's better to test on random numbers. If you specify the 1000 numbers manually, you only know it worked for that specific input.

Comment: BhavikShah @jlordo Yes, I agree with you both. I put the J/K to mean I was just kidding. The better way to test the sort algorithm is generating random values (you can also print the pre-sorted array too to check) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct answer, just hint how to use file, but you can modify the code and make it usable according to your need.

```
    try {

        String str;
                    String[] temp;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your filepath"));

        while ((str= br.readLine()) != null) {
                            temp = str.split(";"); // seperator words bye;
            System.out.println(str);
                    for(int i = 0; i<temp.lenght; i++)
                            System.out.println(temp[i]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need some random numbers to test your sort method:

```
int amount = 1000;
int[] array = new int[amount];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = rand.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a `File` separated by line breaks and use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read line by line, putting them into an array.

An example taken from Scanner documentation page:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
  while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
      long aLong = sc.nextLong();
  }
```

You can easily modify it to get `int` instead of `long` using `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give input 1000 different unique values Random is not an good idea. Random can give same value more than once.